# Como não imprimir a quebra de linha utilizando o console.log()?

Tags: javascript, console

Estou desenvolvendo um programa em JavaScript onde eu tenho que ordenar um *array*, só que estou com um problema na hora da impressão desse array. Eu preciso imprimir tudo em uma linha, com um espaço entre os elementos, e sem espaço no final, porém se eu utilizo o `console.log()` ele já quebra a linha automaticamente, como proceder?

Comment: Parece-me que o que você quer fazer é `console.log(array.join(" "))` ?

Comment: O que é isso ? me explica

Comment: [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) cria uma `string` com todos os elementos nela separados por separador que você indicar, no caso usei o espaço. Todas as respostas que recebeu tem informações úteis que deve de absorver, mas pareceu-me que era isso que estava a tentar fazer, dado o contexto desta pergunta e das suas anteriores.

Comment: Cara, obrigado era exatamente isso que eu queria.

Comment: Da isso como uma resposta Isac.

Comment: Mas isso não responde ao que você está a perguntar hehe. A pergunta que está feita é outra, que é se dá para fazer `console.log` sem quebrar a linha.

Comment: kkk ok então :/

Comment: @Isac Mas dá para postar sim se você der uma ajeitada no texto da resposta. Diga que do jeito que ele pediu não dá, mas que fazendo desse jeito que você sugeriu, deve atender as necessidades dele. Às vezes temos que responder não exatamente o que o autor da pergunta de fato perguntou e sim o que resolve o problema para ele.

Comment: @VictorOCV você diz como aceitar?

Comment: Já aprendi já. v

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é possível, até porque isto foi criado para ajudar no *debug* da sua aplicação, então não precisa de formatação especial. Esta função não imprime na tela.

Se ainda quiser fazer algo nesse sentido o caminho adequado é criar a *string* toda antes e emitir a impressão só depois de tudo pronto, aí você não coloca a quebra em cada **concatenação** que desejar. Dá até para criar uma função sofisticada que faça isso.

Eu colocaria um exemplo melhor se a pergunta tivesse o código que precisa disto, mas seria algo assim:

```
console.log("Exemplo de texto " + variavel + " continua o texto " + "já isso não faz sentido porque a concatenação pode ser eliminada, mas isso pode ser útil: " + var1.toString() + var2.toString());
```

Em um laço:

```
var texto = "";
for (var i = 0; i < var.length; i++) texto += var[i] + " ";
console.log(texto);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/BuildLine.js).

Soluções que não usam o `console.log()` vão imprimir na tela, portanto não resolve seu problema relatado.

Answer (score 3):

A instrução `console.log` tem a finalidade de fazer debug e logging. Ela não serve para mostrar a saída do seu programa, não é para isso que ela foi concebida.

Para mostrar algum texto na saída, considerando-se que você está usando javascript, há diversas maneiras que você pode usar. Para começar, tente alguma das seguintes:

1.

```
var saida = ...;
document.write(saida);
```

2.

```
var saida = ...;
alert(saida);
```

3.

```
var saida = ...;
document.getElementById("algum-elemento-no-html").innerHTML = saida;
```